# XSL calling template within a template is not working

Tags: templates, xslt, junit

How do i call a template within a template. i have a xsl file which contains

```
<xsl:for-each select="execution-output">
<!-- <xsl:if test = "(test-result[@result = 'FAILURE'])and (test-result[@result = 'SKIP']) "> -->
 <xsl:call-template name="failure"/>
<!-- </xsl:if> -->
    </xsl:for-each>
```

i wanted to check if i can call failure template only if test-result = FAILURE or SKIP.

Above snippet is from template testcase and the comment lines are from testsuite. Requirement is i need to call template only for FAILURE and SKIP

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: Your code looks just fine. How does it fail? (Never tell us something "isn't working". Always tell us how it fails. If you tell your doctor "I feel ill", that's not going to be enough for a diagnosis, is it?)

Comment: <test-result
    exectime="2017-12-08 04:38:46.507"
    result="SCRATCH"
    isdone="TRUE"
    logicalname="testSample.TestSuite$1.warning"
    duration="0"
  >
    <test-case
      testcasename="junit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning"
      testunit="ejb20-aqjms"
      testpath="ejb20/aqjms/mdb.test.xml:102: "
>
    </test-case>
    <execution-output errorname="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError">
      <output-details>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in functional.ejb20.aqjms.MdbTest
      </output-details>
    </execution-output>
  </test-result>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`<xsl:if test = "test-result[@result = 'FAILURE' or @result = 'SKIP']">`

Comment: <test-result exectime="2017-12-08 04:38:46.507" result="SCRATCH" isdone="TRUE" logicalname="testSample.TestSuite$1.warning" duration="0" > <test-case testcasename="junit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning" testunit="ejb20-aqjms" testpath="ejb20/aqjms/mdb.test.xml:102: " > </test-case> <execution-output errorname="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError"> <output-details> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in functional.ejb20.aqjms.MdbTest </output-details> </execution-output> </test-result>